# 400 required field resource not found error

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

```
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/regions/[REGION]/addresses
```

calling above api with POST Body

```
{"resource":{"name":"addressName"}}
```

return status code 400 with error message required field resource not found error

[address.insert](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/addresses/insert)

Comment: Try using the try me on the page you linked {"name":"addressName"}

Comment: {"name":"addressName"}  this works.But google docs suggest to use {"resource":{"name":"addressName"}}.

Answer (score 1):

Post the following

```
{"name":"addressName"}
```

In the future its easier to test using try me to get the correct post json values.  The docs are not updated as well as the try me is.